# Create assoc array from dynamically created editable label and input

Tags: jquery, jeditable

A User is abled to add new label and input fields. The label is editable with jeditable. On some event (f.e. click) I´d like to get an assoc array where key is text of label and value is value of corresponding input.

Two questions:

- After changing the text of a label and clicking somewhere else, the
  label jumps back to it´s previously set text (Description). How to
  configure jeditable to keep the new text which should be the key of created array?
- On button click "done" I´m iterating over labels and corresponding   input and pushing values to an array called "values". unfortunately this stays empty, what am I doing wrong here?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    /* Add new Form Fields */
    var a = 0;

    $(".add").click(function() {
        a++;
        $(".userinput").append('<label for="'+a+'">Description</label> <input id="'+a+'" type="text" /><br/>');
    });

    /* Create Assoc array based on label and input */
    $('.done').click(function() {
        var values = [];
        $('input').each(function() {
            var $label = $("label[for='" + this.id + "']").html();
            values[$label] = $(this).val();
        });
        alert(values);
    });

    /* Make label editable */
    $(document.body).on('click', 'label', function() {
        $(this).editable({
            type: 'text'
        });
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jeditable.js/1.7.3/jeditable.min.js"></script>

<div class="userinput"></div>
<button class="add">add new input</button>
<button class="done">done</button>
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/svkq95fk/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use a regular array like an associative array. Use an object instead.

```
var values = {};  //curly brackets instead of square brackets
```

You are also not using Jeditable correctly. The [documentation](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) says that the first parameter must either be a url or a JavaScript function that handles the new value. The second parameter is the configurations object.

```
$(this).editable('the_value_handler.php', {
    type: 'text'
});
////OR
$(this).editable(function (value, settings) {
    console.log (settings);
    return value; 
}, {
    type: 'text'
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/svkq95fk/2/

Personally I would use `console.log` instead of `alert` to output debug information. Popups are rather annoying.

**EDIT**

The documentation also says that the default behavior for clicking outside the editable element is to discard the changes. You can change this with the `onblur` option. https://jsfiddle.net/svkq95fk/4/

```
onblur : cancel Clicking outside editable area cancels changes. Clicking submit button submits changes.
onblur : submit Clicking outside editable area submits changes.
onblur : ignore Click outside editable area is ignored. Pressing ESC cancels changes. Clicking submit button submits changes.
```

Comment: Ok, thanks I have overseen the object and thanks for mentioning the use of jeditable. but still the object is not filled, plus the label does not keep the changed text :( I do not need to send the label to some script all what should happen is that a user can change the label text https://jsfiddle.net/svkq95fk/3/

Comment: @tBook Updated answer for text change problem.

Comment: Perfect! @TreeTree thanks a lot. One more little question. Lets say one adds two new fields and labels hold same text f.e. both name "Description" than when filling the object the first is overwritten. Is there any way of keeping both? Like: Object {Description: "x", Description: "y"}

Comment: @tBook No, how would the code know which one to retrieve when you do `values ['Description']`? You could enforce unique field names or add a counter to duplicate field names like `Description1, Description2`.

Comment: Ok, Mea Culpa stupid question. If I need it I can as you say add some unique piece and split it when needed. Thanks!